# Better choice of convergence for different numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

There are several ways to solve the followings two exercises, but usually only one is the better option in terms of convergence. I need help finding the correct arguments in order to decide which is the better option.

> Find the solution of $x^3-3x^2-3x-4=0$. To do it, we define $f(x)$ s.t. $x=f(x)$ and we use the iterative method $x_{n+1} = f(x_{n})$, i.e., the [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). There are two possible ways;
> \begin{align}
> f_1(x) &= (3x^2+3x+4)^{1/3} =x \\
> f_2(x) &= \frac{1}{3} (x^3-3x^2-4) =x
> \end{align}
> Which is the best option?

I found by my methods that the second option do not converge for any $x_0$. So, obviously, the first option is better in terms of convergence. Anyway, I would like to know if there is an intuitive way to know that.

> Find the solutions for $e^{2x} = x+6$ using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). There are two possible ways;
> \begin{align}
> g_1(x) &=e^{2x} -x-6 = 0 \\
> g_2(x) &= e^{-2x} (x+6)-1 = 0
> \end{align}
> Which is the best option? Prove that the initial point is a right choice. Estimate the number of iterations that have to be done in order to find the solution of $g_{1,2}(x)=0$ correct to $16$ decimal places.

I don't know which is the better option as to convergence. Neither how to prove that the chosen initial point is a good choice.

Thanks!

Comment: For the first, yes, I know the how to test the convergence. For the second, that iteration is Newton's method, but I'm just using it in the second example, not in the first one.

Comment: I was asking about an intuitive way to know that. Anyway, how can I estimate the number of estimations that have to be done in order to find the solution with a certain error? (In the example of Newton's method).

Comment: I didn't provide anything, I'm asking for a efficient way to find them. That link post was useful, thanks.